# Which statement of Hadamard's factorization theorem is true?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Genus_of_an_entire_function) wikipedia article it says that if the order $\rho$, and the genus $g$ of an entire function can satisfy the equation $$g=\rho+1, $$ if the order is an integer.

However, in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis text, Hadamard's theorem states that always $$g \leq \rho \leq g+1. $$

I see that as a contradiction, since $g=\rho+1$ is strictly greater than $\rho$. Is there an error in the wikipedia article? or maybe in Ahlfors' text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the genus of an entire function does not exceed its order. So Ahlfors is right. Perhaps the confusion with $g=[\rho]$ comes from different understandings of the Gauss bracket in the Wikipedia article. Here $[x]$ should be understood as the floor function.